# Detecting an air-tap-and-hold with OnInputClicked method

Tags: onclick, augmented-reality, hololens

I am writing a program that needs to detect the difference between a long air-tap-and-hold vs. a quick air tap. Currently, I am using the following code to detect quick airtaps:

```
#region IInputClickHandler
public void OnInputClicked(InputClickedEventData eventData)
{
 // stuff being done is coded here
}
#endregion IInputClickHandler
```

which works well, but is there a similar code to detect long taps? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways of detecting a hold. For just a generic hold gesture, you can inherit and use the `IHoldHandle` interface. If you want to get an updated state, you should either use the `IManipulationHandler` or the `INavigationHandler` interface.

If you are testing in the editor, use the manipulation handler instead as you can't test the navigation in the editor but it works on the HoloLens.

Comment: Thank you! To add info for anyone else with the same question: make sure you implement all the methods given since you're using an interface (listed here: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit/Input/Scripts/InputHandlers/IHoldHandler.cs), even you don't actually do anything with them.